# Is it safe and secure to use JDBC in android?

Tags: java, android, security, jdbc

I have this for a long time in my mind, but I can't find the answer yet. I have a `MySQL` database and I would love to connect my android application to it by using `JDBC`. The question is, how secure it will be. The SQL injection is not a problem while using the prepared statements and escaping everything, but, if the application get cracked and the source codes decompiled, can the potential hacker see the connection parameters like the link to the database, username and password?

Is it secure to use `JDBC` on android devices, or it is unsecure and unsafe?

If not, what do you suggest as the safest way to connect to a `MySQL` database, or a webservice is still the best option for now?

Comment: Use a network controller that will accept data payloads, and then submit data to the database itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardcoding credentials into your app is pretty much a bad idea, because if someone who has some knowledge about this subject, actually will try cracking you app, and if your app manages some financial sensitive data, they actually will try triplify efforts.

As far as security goes, in this kind of architecture it seems that a *Asymmetric encryption* algorithm is what best fits this kind of transactions, as you can hardcode/download each time you need the public key for encrypting messages and they'll be only decrypted by the server side using the private key.

I'd recommend using a web-service with `TLS` encryption, it won't be 100% secure but at least it will harden things to crackers enough.

- [How to securely share key between two remote devices?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53631/how-to-securely-share-key-between-two-remote-devices)
- [How dangerous might be publishing a public key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54353/how-dangerous-might-be-publishing-a-public-key)

Answer (score 2):

In case of mobiles there no such thing as perfect reception so you get dropped calls and missing data when the user moves in and out of good reception.

The JDBC protocol isn't designed to handle the complete/partial disconnect that occurs in mobile, especially when you are in the middle of a query. HTTP on the other hand at least allows you to design in your own retry mechanism as a failed HTTP request is just a failed HTTP request and not an exception bubbling up from the network layer/JDBC driver.